# creating blockly block connections to blocks in code

Tags: blockly

I have implemented a context menu handler that adds a block to the workspace.  I am trying to add the block in between the block that summoned the context menu and any blocks that may already be connected to it ( previousConnection ).  What I'm shooting for and the code I've got and what it does...

```
context menu option handler:
   var option =
   {
      text: "Comment",
      enabled: true,
      callback: function ()
      {
         var comment = workspace.newBlock('ta_comment');
         var block = Blockly.ContextMenu.currentBlock;

         block.previousConnection.connect(comment.nextConnection);

         comment.initSvg();
         comment.render();
      }
   }

   menuOptions.push(option);
```

[before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzjJS.png)
[after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJUVI.png)

Comment: Remember, before connecting comment, to save the target connection of `block.previousConnection`.  If it is not null, you will need to connect `comment.previousConnection` to it.

Comment: makes sense but what would that look like? I've tried a couple of things with mixed results.  for instance the below works until you run it a third time on the same block and then it disconnects the block and coment blocks...         var comment = workspace.newBlock('ta_comment');
         var block = Blockly.ContextMenu.currentBlock;
         var targetConnection = block.previousConnection.targetConnection;
         block.previousConnection.connect(comment.nextConnection);
         comment.previousConnection.connect( targetConnection );

Answer (score 1):

```
     //create comment block and get the block that summoned the context menu
     var comment = workspace.newBlock('ta_comment');
     var block = Blockly.ContextMenu.currentBlock;

     //connect up comment block
     comment.previousConnection.connect(block.previousConnection.targetConnection);
     comment.nextConnection.connect(block.previousConnection);

     //init
     comment.initSvg();

     //render updated workspace
     workspace.render();
```